# What is rank function r(a)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am working on the propositional logic and trying to understand the rank function.

In my text there is a definition;
Assume, X = N. Define $G_A(A_i) = 0, H_¬(x) = x + 1$, and $H_→(x, y) = max(x, y) + 1$.
We call the function G as in the proposition the rank function.

Then there is an exercise;
Show that $r(φ)$ is at most the number of occurrences of connectives of $φ$. (r is the rank function)

My question is what is the rank function? When I write $H_¬(x) = x + 1$ I can understand that the "not" symbol add 1 for rank function but I cannot understand meaning of $H_→(x, y) = max(x, y) + 1$. I could not write an example and I could not prove my exercise.

Comment: An atomic formulas has zero connectives and thus its *rank* is $0$. And so on.

Comment: The function counts in a sense the complexity of a formula that is related to but not equal to the number of connectives. It is the "level" in the construction tre of the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is the depth of a formula’s expression tree. One measure of the complexity of a formula, it's how many subformulas you have to go through to get down to the deepest propositional variable. If you are not familiar with [trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure) in Logic or Computer Science, the depth of a subformula is also how many pairs of parentheses surround it when the formula is written out in a fully parenthesized form (even subformulas with $\lnot$, contrary to the convention in Wikipedia described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula#Propositional_calculus)). It’s particularly useful when thinking about computer algorithms that work with formulas.

From the notion of rank as the depth of the deepest propositional variable, binary connectives (like $\implies$) “bury” both the left and right hand side one deeper (or surround them with one more set of parentheses). That’s where the 1 comes from, just like with “not”.

In determining the rank of the new formula, only the subformula with the highest rank matters - it's the one with the deepest propositional variable - max is a simple way of selecting the rank of that deeper subformula.

Proving the rank is at most the number of connectives is often done by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction). Using induction, we first prove a condition holds for rank 0 formulas, then, assuming the condition holds for all formulas with rank $n$ or less, we prove the condition holds for formulas with rank $n+1$.

To give an outline: Propositional variables have no connectives and zero rank, so the condition holds for the base case of the induction.

A new formula adds one connective and one to the rank of its deepest subformula; since we assume that the condition holds for the subformula, adding one to the number of connectives makes sure that the increased rank is still bounded by the number of connectives.

Because, with a binary connective, one side’s rank doesn’t get counted  its connectives are effectively ignored in the rank of the new formula; the result is the rank may be smaller than the number of connectives.